# jQuery validation plugin - init status

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin to validate a form. To add and remove rules dynamicly the Validator have to be there already. How can i figure this out? In other words: Is there something like a init-callback?

Comment: **You shouldn't ever need an init callback**.   Where is your code?  How/when do you call `.validate()`?  Just use the `.rules()` method any time _after_ `.validate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to check if `$.fn.validate` is a function by using `typeof`:

```
if (typeof $.fn.validate === 'function') {
    ...
}
```

If `$.fn.validate` isn't loaded, `typeof $.fn.validate` will return `undefined`.

Comment: What does $.fn.validate mean? The plugin is loaded or the validate-method is attached to my form and Validator is there?

Comment: jQuery plugins extend jQuery's `fn` object. All jQuery plugins which are called using `$('elem').pluginName()` will appear as `$.fn.pluginName`, as they were created using jQuery's `$.fn.extend` method: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/.

Comment: Your answer is correct but this dont work in my case. I need an event that told me: "you can use the add-rule-method now because Validator is attached to my form".

Comment: @domBro82, you control exactly when the call to `.validate()` happens so why you would need an initialization callback is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

To check if function is loaded, you can try with:

```
if ( $.isFunction($.fn.validate) ) {

}
```